# What is the name for a graph where nodes store a list of other nodes?

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

For example, look at this representation of a graph https://github.com/thomasdane/algoDataStructures/blob/master/algorithms/graphs/getUser.js

It is an array of nodes, and each node stores a list of connections/neighbors.

To traverse it, you start at a node and check the connections.

This doesn't seem to fit within the two common graph representations - adjacency list and adjacency matrix.

Is this a valid way to represent a graph? If so, does it have a name?

Comment: That's an adjacency list representation.

Comment: *"Is this a valid way to represent a graph?"* Why wouldn't it be? It's not like there is an International Graph Authority which would prosecute you if they dislike the way you represent your graphs.